# Cross-close icon not appearing

Tags: javascript, css, slide

I understand I need to enter the codes for you guys however the source code page is very long.

Rather this is the site: www.blasonmoderne.com
I should think you would be able to look at page source.

What is happening is on each "slide" in "portfolio" then say "police logo" the slide coming next does not show at all on left or right top end corner. You can catch a glimpse of the arrow when slides are changing in "behind" the slide.

I don't know how to fix this at all and this is my own site and does not need any glitch obviously for prospective client to have a good experience.

Thank you in advance even though I have not put the codes.

Beau

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en"><head>

            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"    content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-                 scale=1.0"> 
            <title>Anglais &amp; Communication Emmanuel Goussot</title>
            <meta name="description" content="Un professionnel de la                communication et de la formation. En recherche active d'emploi. English                 Teacher for now             and looking for solid work" />
            <meta name="keywords" content="cours anglais, anglais dijon,  formation, cpf,               communication, dijon" />
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico"> 
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/               component.css" />

            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css76/demo76.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css76/component76.css"   />

                    <script>
                (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;   i[r]=i[r]||function(){
                (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new    Date();a=s.createElement(o),
                    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;                   m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
                    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com  /analytics.js','ga');

                ga('create', 'UA-10000488-1', 'blasonmoderne.com');
                ga('send', 'pageview');

                </script>
                <script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button   /buttons.js"></             script>
                <script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: "701f945f-6594-4301-             b330-e329855990a6", doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false,                             hashAddressBar: true});</script>

            <style type="text/css"> 
            .container #bl-main section .bl-content .bottom.page

                a   {
            @font-face 
            font-family: 'icomoon';
            src:url('../fonts/icomoon.eot');
            src:url('../fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('../fonts/icomoon.woff') format('woff'),
            url('../fonts/icomoon.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('../fonts/icomoon.svg#icomoon') format('svg');
            margin: 0;
            font-size: 1em;
            text-align: left;
            font-family: Lato, Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
            text-transform: lowercase;
            color: #f2ede3;
                }
                </style>

                <style type="text/css">
                .container #bl-main #bl-panel-work-items div div .bottom.page2
            a {
            @font-face 
            font-family: 'icomoon';
            src:url('../fonts/icomoon.eot');
            src:url('../fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('../fonts/icomoon.woff') format('woff'),
            url('../fonts/icomoon.ttf') format('truetype'),
            url('../fonts/icomoon.svg#icomoon') format('svg');
            margin: 0;
            font-size: 1em;
            text-align: left;
            font-family: Lato, Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
            color: #f2ede3;
                }
                    </style>
                <link rel="alternate" href="www.blasonmoderne.com" hreflang="fr-fr" />
                <link rel="alternate" href="www.blasonmoderne.com" hreflang="en-uk" />

                <script>
                (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;   i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)                     [0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com    /analytics.js','ga');

                ga('create', 'UA-10000488-1', 'auto');
                ga('send', 'pageview');

                </script>
```